# Service with multiple broadcastreceivers

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service running in background and a broadcastreceiver that alerts me when an app is installed. Can i register another broadcastreceiver that notifies me when an app is uninstalled, in the same service?

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    ...

public class InstallationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        public InstallationReceiver() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "DS notify APP INSTALLED").show();

        }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //Set the intentFilter and register the receiver
    counter++;
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast ts = Toast.makeText(this, "Ds Started"+counter+" times" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    ts.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
    ts.show();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    receiver = new InstallationReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast ts = Toast.makeText(this, "Ds stopped" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    ts.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
    ts.show();
}
```

**EDIT:** Added code of my working code with only a receiver for installation events. It is nested in service class, so i don't need to declare it as receiver in manifest. My question is: Can i nest another receiver (I.E. receiver for uninstall events) in the same way i did for installation receiver?

Comment: how about create a Receiver before the Service Stops?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible even with just the original broadcast receiver, you just need to go into your manifest and add the necessary intent to that receivers intent-filter. Registering another receiver to accomplish this is acceptable if you don't want to bother coding up the logic to differentiate between the two, and is probably a better situation long term if you plan on adding different functionality.

I don't know myself what specific intent there is to listen for an uninstall, but if you found the install intent, it should be similar.

Comment: I edited my question, with my working code for a single receiver. I wanna know if i can nest another receiver in the same service class file, just as i did for installationreceiver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do pretty much anything in this area, just listen register to get a PACKAGE_REMOVED intent

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#7